# Dictionary sorts by hash not by sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have appsettings.json and I want get them all, and put to dictionary.

```
 var conf = configuration.GetSection("Configuration");
 var serverConf = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 foreach (var item in conf.AsEnumerable())
 {
    if (item.Value != null && item.Key != null)
    {
         serverConf.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
 }
```

but this code sorts by I don't know, maybe hash? not by sequence, not by alphabetical.It should be by sequence

My appsettings:

```
 "Configuration": {
    "response_type": "id_token token",
    "scope": "openid profile api1",
    "start_checksession": true,
    "silent_renew": false,
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean? note that the order of elements in a dictionary are non-deterministic.

Comment: Why do you want to sort it by sequence in dictionary?

Comment: But If i print serverConf, then first element would be not "response_type". Becasue the order must be exactly like my appsettings

Comment: But you can sort it as you want when print. Show us the code

Comment: I can't. If I use conf.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Key) then will be sort by alphabetical

Comment: @user3577896: What do you mean by "nothing will change"? That will print it in descending alphabetical order. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve at the moment.

Comment: Yes, by alphabetical - sorry. But this must be by sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary<,>` doesn't guarantee *any* particular ordering. If you require a particular sort order, you should use a different data structure.

For configuration, however, I'd say that requiring any particular ordering is a smell in itself. It would be okay to need to *transform* it into a particular stable ordering for the sake of (say) obtaining some hash, but that's easy enough to do with LINQ, e.g.

```
var ordered = settings.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key);
```

But if you really need "original file order" you probably want to work with a different data model to start with, e.g. a `JObject` representing the actual JSON. I would suggest thinking hard about whether your current desire to do so is really a concrete requirement though, and whether there's a different way to achieve the same bigger goal.

Comment: This will be by alphabetical - not sequence

Comment: @user3577896: Yes, that's why I said that would just transform it into a particular stable ordering. I didn't claim it would be the original ordering - as I've said, I would be wary of such a requirement, and in order to achieve it you'd probably need to load the JSON file directly. I can't find any documentation that guarantees that the key/value pairs returned by `IConfigurationSection.AsEnumerable` will be in the original order.

Comment: Hmm, but what can I get this? If I use IConfigurationSection.GetSection it will be sorted..

Comment: @user3577896: Are you sure? I don't see it being documented that way, so I'd at least be somewhat cautious. (It may be in the right order now, but not later.) If that works for you, just use that - don't put it into a dictionary.