# C# ASP.NET AppSettings.json loading order

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, appsettings

I´ve got a Configuration Model which holds a Dictionary which is configured in AppSettings.json.

It loads the elements but not in the order which is configured.

AppSettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Configuration": {
    "Separator": ";",
    "CsvMapping": {
      "Firstname": "firstname",
      "Lastname": "lastname",
      "State": "state",
      "Info": "info"
    }
  }
}
```

My Configuration-Model:

```
public class Configuration : IConfiguration
{
    public string Separator { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> CsvMapping { get; set; }
}
```

The loaded order of the Dictionary is:

```
State, Info, Lastname, Firstname
```

But I do want to have the order of the AppSettings.json. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: If you want a particular order, don't use a Dictionary but a dedicated class with Lirstname/Lastname/State/Info fields. This question is more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957049/dictionary-sorts-by-hash-not-by-sequence , except for the explicit "is there a way to do so" question at the end.

Comment: you also should be explicit about the ordering in the config - don't assume that it will load in order

Comment: The benefit of using a dictionary is that regardless of the position of a key, it's lookup time is the same. If you do need them in a specific order, you probably don't want a dictionary.